# Can I get the "Saints Flow" effect outside of the DLC mission it appears in?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

I recently finished *The Trouble With Clones* and I really enjoyed the sequences that involved the Saints Flow effect - throwing fireballs and running faster than cars was a lot of fun.  I'd like to be able to use this elsewhere, or just go on a non-mission-related rampage.

I can't find Saints Flow in my inventory or in my crib storage or anything similar to that.  Is there any way to play with this ability outside of the related DLC mission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to use the (awesome) powers that the Saints Flow drink gives you during *The Trouble With Clones*. The Saints Flow effect isn't granted through a specific power-up or anything, it's just an effect turned on for the duration of the "Send in the Clones" mission of the DLC. However, it *is* replayable, so you can replay the last mission if you go through it again.

Comment: This makes me sad :(  Thanks for the info, though!

Answer (score 3):

If you're playing on the PC, you can install the [**Sandbox+**](https://www.saintsrowmods.com/forum/threads/sandbox-for-srtt.1076/) mod, which allows toggling of the Saints Flow superpowers (among other features) in the open world, even outside of the mission it originally appeared in. You can even use it while doing activities. In some of the screenshots below, I was able to use the Saints Flow super powers while doing a Survival diversion.

'Saints Flow' powers in action with Sandbox+:
[image: http://www.pcgamer.com/2013/08/25/mod-of-the-week-sandbox-v-2-for-saints-row-the-third/][image][image][image]

The keys that toggle the Saints Flow superpowers with Sandbox+ are <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.

Answer (score -4):

you can get the powers if you try to jump of a really tall buliding without using your parachute and land on a car there's a glitch then suddenely there's fireballs in your inventory.

Comment: ..seems legit :P